# scikit-learn: get selected features when using SelectKBest within pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do features selection as a part of the a scikit-learn pipeline, on a multi-label scenario. My purpose is to select best K features, for some given k.

It might be simple, but I don't understand how to get the selected features indices in such a scenario.

on a regular scenario I could do something like that:

```
anova_filter = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10)

anove_filter.fit_transform(data.X, data.Y)

anova_filter.get_support()
```

but on a multilabel scenario my labels dimensions are #samples X #unique_labels so fit and fit_transform yield the following exception:
ValueError: bad input shape

which makes sense, because it expects labels of dimension [#samples]

on the multilabel scenario, it makes sense to do something like that:

```
clf = Pipeline([('f_classif', SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10)),('svm', LinearSVC())])

multiclf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf, n_jobs=-1)

multiclf.fit(data.X, data.Y)
```

but then the object I'm getting is of type sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier which doesn't have a get_support function. How do I get the trained SelectKBest model when it's used during a pipeline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you set it up, there will be one SelectKBest per class. Is that what you intended?
You can get them via

```
multiclf.estimators_[i].named_steps['f_classif'].get_support()
```

If you want one feature selection for all the OvR models,
you can do

```
clf = Pipeline([('f_classif', SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10)),
                ('svm', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])
```

and get the single feature selection with

```
clf.named_steps['f_classif'].get_support()
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I actually tried it but I get the  ValueError: bad input shape exception. It seems like it doesnt get the multilebel scenario, even though I use OneVsRestClassifier. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which one did you try? The first one? Without the traceback I can't really say.

Comment: OK, some debugging and representation changes and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: clf.name_steps['f_classif'].get_support() should read as clf.named_steps['f_classif'].get_support()  there is a "d" missing at the end of the "named"

Comment: Hi .. the indices returned via get_support(indices = True) and those returned via the p_values (after selecting the smallest 'k' p-values) don't seem to be the same. Can you please shed some light on this?

Comment: It uses the f scores but that shouldn't really make a difference?

Comment: Does Selectkbest  in the pipeline executes only on the train phase isn't it? I mean when I do pipe.predict(X_test) selectkbest does not execute anymore. Did I get It right?